# Why notepad++ autocomplete doesn't work with function arguments?

Tags: php, text-editor, notepad++

I checked "Settings > Prefences > Backup/Auto-Completion > Enable Auto-completion on each input" and "Function parameters hint on input" options. I have Notepad++ 5.9 (unicode) version. It auto completes function names but not their arguments. Also i tried re-install. I know it has this feature but not working. Any idea why?

I mean it auto completes print_r when i write "pri" but i want it to work like in the image;
http://i51.tinypic.com/3322auc.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm, this is not an answer to your question but I want to share it anyway.

I have used Notepad++ for years. I didn't like Eclipse and NetBeans is just so damn slow.
I never used the auto complete function for anything.
Notepad++ can't really do any code analysis, it can only give you auto-completion on the known PHP functions.

I've since switched to an IDE that does full code analysis and can do auto-completion for your own code as well.

Notepad++ is great if you just want to write something real quick. It's also a great tool if you want to learn about PHP since it doesn't do auto-completion very well ;) but if you really want to be productive when you're working on a large application I recommend you use an IDE that does code analysis. Productivity is the key here. I spend less time looking through files and more time actually writing code, which is great! :D

Good IDEs for PHP: NetBeans, PHPStorm, Eclipse.

Comment: I know it's not an IDE but it has this feature and it's not working. So my question is still unanswered.

Comment: Hmm, I checked and it doesn't work for `print_r`, but it does work for `substr`. Regardless though, Notepad++'s auto-completion isn't powerful enough to be of any significant use.

Answer (score 5):

For this feature to work, you need to supply an .xml file which contains the appropriate functions and parameters.

An example for Javascript with installation instructions can be found [here](http://www.unifycommunity.com/wiki/index.php?title=Using_Notepad_Plus_Plus_as_a_script_editor#How_to_add_Intellisense_.28called_Auto-Completion_in_Notepad.2B.2B.29_for_Unityscript).

I have not yet found xml files for PHP (or Python, which I'm looking for). But it seems this can work in npp, you just need to locate the right xml file.

Best of luck!

(Oh, and don't listen to the naysayers who are too quick to give up, npp works fine as an IDE.)

Comment: Link is broken. Can anyone else point to a file containing all function and their parameters declarations for javascript?

Comment: Link broken please resuply

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ it's very good text editor, but it's not IDE.
Try to use IDE - [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) or [PhpStorm](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Web+IDE+EAP), and you will get much more than just smart autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same question about this， function hint is Ok，but param hints not display until I download a new release of notepad++(a not install release), all is ok. before, I tryed many time, and edit the xml files.

If you will edit you own language, Can copy from a exist language xml ,for cpp.xml in plugins/APIs folder. It's easy to understand its rule.

It is very easy to have a error， if you config file is changed.